# Vertx mongo client overwhelming mongodb with concurrent updates

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

Trying to build a reactive system with use of `akka, rx, vert.x and mongodb` where the flow (downstream) looks pretty much:

`publisher -> akka streams -> rx streams -> vert.x event bus -> vert.x mongo rx client -> mongo client`

I ran into a situation where the upstream invokes too many update collection actions on mongo, and it ends up with:

`com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.`

The `updateCollection`:

- is triggered concurrently by about `10 publishers` each pushing element every `0.1 second`
- is performed on the same collection
- is performing addition of a new element to an array embedded in a document

**1)** As this is a reactive system, it would be nice to backpressure the source, to perform a http request only as often, as it makes it possible to write to mongo - so that the queue of threads waiting for connection to mongo wouldn't grow,

Is there any pattern/example, for such a backpressure with mongo, to follow or should I invent and implement it on my own ?

How can I access and observe the number of threads with awaiting connection via the vertx mongo client ?

**2)** While looking into the code of vertx mongo client it turns out that it's not keeping the connection to mongo open, and the new session is being opened for every update action.
You can observe this in `io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.updateCollection(...)` where underneath it calls `MongoCollection.updateOne(...)` without passing the `ClientSession clientSession` parameter.

While 10 concurrent updates per second seem a small number, the question is - may it be the case that the creation of `ClientSession` is taking a long time and therefore causes the threads to queue ?

Also what would be the design decisions for not caching the connection to mongo in the vertx mongo client ?

The `mongostat` is:

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw  arw net_in net_out conn                time
    *0    *0     32     *0       0   139|0  9.8% 10.8%       0 1.84G  666M 0|0 1|89  29.6k   62.9k  104 Jan 19 02:33:51.980
    *0    *0      6     *0       0     4|0 18.7% 18.7%       0 2.90G 1.50G 0|0 1|100  2.41k   9.59k  104 Jan 19 02:33:59.342
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     2|0 15.7% 17.2%       0 3.52G 1.60G 0|0  1|97   493b   7.90k  104 Jan 19 02:34:07.480
    *0    *0      9     *0       0     3|0 14.7% 17.2%       0 3.52G 1.57G 0|0 1|100  3.10k   18.7k  104 Jan 19 02:34:10.955
    *0    *0      1     *0       0     1|0 21.4% 23.1%       0 3.52G 1.57G 0|0 1|100   749b   7.46k  104 Jan 19 02:34:19.579
    *0    *0     10     *0       0    16|0 36.7% 37.4%       0 3.57G 1.57G 0|0 1|100  4.79k   73.7k  104 Jan 19 02:34:20.443
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     9|0 53.6% 54.0%       0 3.62G 1.56G 0|0 1|100  1.33k   47.6k  104 Jan 19 02:34:21.769
    *0    *0      1     *0       0    13|0 54.5% 55.2%       0 3.62G 1.57G 0|0 1|100  1.92k   70.6k  104 Jan 19 02:34:22.659
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0    23|0 70.5% 70.9%       0 3.62G 1.56G 0|0 1|100  2.75k    122k  104 Jan 19 02:34:23.173
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0    31|0 72.1% 72.5%       0 3.62G 1.58G 0|0 1|100  3.56k    153k  104 Jan 19 02:34:23.586
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: check that connections aquired from the connection pool are released. Find in the stack trace PooledConnectionProvider.get() and make sure that this call is paired with PooledConnectionProvider.release().

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you need an backpreasure because if you get more than you process all the time it will allocate all memory and course exception in your case but i think the choose is to create en emitter where every stream emit item to this emitter and use mongorepo.saveAll(emitter) :

processor1 ->

processor2 ->

processor3 ->

processor4 ->

processor5    -> EMITTING TO EMITTER - EMITTER SAVING TO MONGO using saveAll(emmiter)

processor6 ->

processor7 ->

processor8 ->

processor9 ->

processor10 ->

Comment: I don't understand much from your response. If you are referring to spring-data MongoRepository, I'm not using spring-data but vertx-mongo-client, as stated in the question. Also I've applied a simple backpressure on my own and it solves the issue, though it's not an answer to the question.